# How can I use a template in a function to pass two different type of parameters?

Tags: java, c++, function, templates

For example, let:

```
T div(T num1, T num2)
```

where `T` is a template type.

```
return num1/num2;
```

If we want to call and return the answer in data type of the first parameter:

```
div(4.0,4);
```

What change should be made with the function definition?  I have tried using two template classes, but got an error.

Comment: I believe C has no notion of template parameters. Java and C++ are different languages. Choose one

Comment: @Amadeus i know that template is features are available in c++ only. But i thought people khowing c can also answer to this. So i included the tag. Now as i am trying to remove the tag s its not working.

Comment: Can you provide full (though not working due to the error you mentioned) example(s) of your attempt(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++, you could add one more template parameter, e.g.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 div(T1 num1, T2 num2) {
    return num1/num2;
}
```